# Why can a long jumper jump further by flipping?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Back in the 1970s a long jumper introduced a technique which potentially enabled them to travel slightly further by going into a [front flip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJ6ySgqjONI) during the jump (the technique was quickly banned for safety reasons).  I was wondering why this rotation of the body enables the athlete to travel slightly further.

The two natural answers seem to be that (a) when a longer jumper takes off they are sort of fighting rotation anyway so it is more efficient in terms of energy loss to just not fight the rotation (no power lost in inhibiting forward momentum) and (b) resistance due to drag force is slightly reduced.

Are there any other possible reasons?  Would the reduced drag force make enough of a difference for it to be worthwhile as a technique?

Comment: "Potentially" is not "actually" for everyone. But, like the Fosbury Flop you should pay attention to where the center-of-gravity is during the motions to compare them.

Comment: For pole vaulting and Fosbury flop, there is a bar to clear so the athlete to bends their back around the bar at the peak, meaning the body is clear whilst the centre of mass is under the bar, how does this work in this case?

Comment: I was not saying they are the same, but that following the center-of-gravity through the motions might be revealing. Body contortions that maximize com and minimize length of body parts below the com get you further.

Comment: What do you mean by the ''path of the CM'' as the path above the ground which  the CM follows moves as if the body is a point particle subject to gravity. Tucking once in the air does not affect the position/path of the CM.  Did you mean in the frame of the lower body or something like that?